# Trying to create a bar graph with error bars but I keep facing this issue (new to coding)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't have many data points so I decided to just manually type them in
I'm assuming the program doesn't like the format of my data but I don't know what to do to fix it

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- data.frame(
  name=c("a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g"),
  value=c(0.0,1641.10,63.20,30.80,245.59,46.14,41.95),
  sd=c(0,1055.21,75.13,28.53,179.48,46.82,33.70)
)

ggplot(data1) + 
    geom_bar( aes(x=name,y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7) +
    geom_errorbar( aes(x=name, ymin=value-sd,ymax=value+sd), width=0.4, color="orange",alpha=0.9,size=1,3)
```

Searched around online but didn't find anything that directly answered my problem so either I'm not asking the right questions on google or I didn't notice the solution in front of me

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this that you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- data.frame(name=c("a","b","c","d", "e", "f", "g"),
                    value=c(0.0,1641.10,63.20,30.80,245.59,46.14,41.95),
                    sd=c(0,1055.21,75.13,28.53,179.48,46.82,33.70))
                    
min = data1$value-data1$sd
max = data1$value+data1$sd

data1 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(min = min, max = max)


ggplot(data1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=name,y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=name, ymin = min, ymax = max), width = 0.4)
```

You can tweak the colours and whatnot yourself, but I believe this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data1 %>%
  mutate(min = value - sd,
         max = value + sd) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = name, ymin = min, ymax = max), width = 0.4, color = "orange", alpha = 0.9)
```